# How to output a raster of special case's distribution with regard to overall distribution?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, density, correlation, distribution

For example, the crime scenes are unevenly distributed in a city. Each case's scene can be represented as a point. Thus, we can generate a raster map, which shows the crime scenes' density in this city.

Also, we can draw such a type of raster for any particular crime type, like homicide.

Suppose we have generated a density raster for overall cases and a density raster for homicide only. Now I want to find the correlation between the distributions of homicide and overall cases. In other words, I want to find the place which have a significant higher homicide risk, with regard to overall crime distribution in this city.

Now I can only think about the raster calculator in ArcGIS, but I am afraid if it oversimplifies my issue. Is there any other tool in ArcToolbox could better solve my question? Any recommendation is welcomed.

Comment: Find ratio and pick peaks.

Comment: Presuming those are point incidences, you may want to create two *Kernel density* rasters and then follow @FelixIP 's suggestion.